# How to replace a text in XML file using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a XML file and a XSLT file as below

Check.xml

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

Check.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:for-each select="/">
<xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="country='USA'">
         <xsl:copy-of select="CHK"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I try to transform it i get the below error

```
Error:XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() [<a href='xsltprocessor.transformtoxml'>xsltprocessor.transformtoxml</a>]: No stylesheet associated to this object
```

What Iam trying to do here is that check if the  value is "USA" and if yes the replace USA with "CHK" String.

Iam not getting where I am going wrong or if Iam not using the correct syntax's.
I am a newbie to XSLT and just got started with this. Any help is greatly appreciated!!!
The output I am expecting is

```
<catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
            <country>**CHK**</country>
            <company>Columbia</company>
            <price>10.90</price>
            <year>1985</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Hide your heart</title>
            <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>CBS Records</company>
            <price>9.90</price>
            <year>1988</year>
        </cd>
</catalog>
```

Comment: There isn't a `<CHK>` element in your XML. Please update your question and give an example of what you'd like your output XML to look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="country[. = 'USA']">
    <country>**CHK**</country>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied to the provided XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpyÂ® -->
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

**...the desired output is produced:**

```
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>**CHK**</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

**Explanation:**

- The first template is the [`Identity Transform`](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html) - its job is to output all nodes and attributes from the source document to the result document as-is.
- The second template overrides the Identity Transform by matching any `<country>` element whose value is "USA". In this case, a new `<country>` element is created and given the desired value.

I recommend you look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589) for some great XSLT learning resources.

Comment: Thanks but iam still getting the same error pasted above. Please help :( This is the link where I am checking it. http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php

Comment: Not sure what to tell you as I didn't create that online-toolz.com site. As it is, I just tested my solution there and got the correct result. Going forward, I recommend that you install a sensible XSLT parser on your own machine - start here: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/InstallingAProcessor.html